# What happens if two pages have the same WebPartId?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, page-layout

I have to programatically create new Sharepoint pages (~50). To do so, I've created a template page and I simply copy the information I want inside this template using a macro made in Visual Studio.

Then I copy all the files to the library with SharePoint Designer. The template was create with the Sharepoint Icon (new document) and copied to my hard drive.

However, I noticed that it has a HTML field "WebParID" which changes each time a create a page inside sharepoint.

When I generate all my pages from my macro, they obviously all have the same WebPartID since it is based from my static template..

So My question is

**"What happens if all my pages have the same webpartID ?"**

As a side question, I'll be eager to know how I could get a WebPartID using Visual Studio.

Thank you all!

Comment: try it and see what happens.